# I want to prevent Google Market from upgrading to Google Play store

Tags: google-play-store, application-autoupdate

my HTC desire HD wont download from the Google Play Store , but will from the Google Market.
How do I stop the phone from automatically upgrading ?

Answer (score 3):

If you're rooted, then use an app to freeze the `MarketUpdater.apk` app.

You can also remove that app from the `/system/app` directory.

Without that app, the market/Google Play won't automatically update.

There is no way to prevent market updates without root.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,makes sense.How do I root the phone?Dont think it is as I have never done anything to it.Checked and can only force stop system/app.

Comment: Google HTC Desire HD root. Check forums such as http://forum.xda-developers.com `/system/app` is a file path BTW.

Comment: @LiamW With ICS or higher, wouldn't it be enough to freeze the `MarketUpdater.apk` to keep it from running? If so, at least users with ICS and up had a way without root.

Comment: @Izzy Forgot about that, edited answer to include it - thanks :)

Comment: So it does really work this way? Some of the Google apps register broadcast listeners which somehow even survive a freeze (cannot remember the source for this, but I recently read about such an issue). So if you are as unsure as I am, maybe better use a conditional like "should" or "might" ;) Sure it's worth a try at least, and it *should* work. But unless proved... who knows?

Comment: Removed it. I think they may have changed the system for ICS plus users - I can't find an updater app, but I am running 4.2 so...

Comment: Thanks for all the help,much appreciated.I will try to get the phone rooted and see how I am fixed after that.Paul

Comment: I've used Titanium on 2.3 and freeze worked properly. Not sure about 4.2 tho, I've never had to prevent update after jumping to ICS.